# How to merge master branch in local feature branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, feature-branch

In one of case I have created an branch and started to work on. I keep on commit & push changes in local branch but did not merge in master & neither pulled any changes from master.

Now I'm done with local branch changes. I followed [derekgourlay tutorial](https://www.derekgourlay.com/blog/git-when-to-merge-vs-when-to-rebase/) & followed following steps to merge my project.

```
git fetch origin

git rebase −p origin/develop
```

First it game me number of conflict which was obvious but changes that I committed in my local branch those are not there after merge.

Am I missing anything. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't merging `develop` with `feature` branch instead of `rebasing`? `git pull origin develop`?

Comment: I'll try, but could you add what is add-on if we use pull instead of rebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` develop branch with your `feature` branch.

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git pull origin develop       # pull (fetch + merge) develop branch into feature
$ git push origin HEAD          # update remote/feature
```